# Javascript: cancel or let an event continue?

Tags: javascript, events, kendo-ui, dom-events

My scenario deals with Kendo UI, but I think it probably applies to JavaScript generally, hence the JavaScript tag.

I have a Kendo scheduler with the edit event option set to functionA.

In functionA, I create a Kendo window (basically a modal) that asks the user a question; in one case the edit event should continue and bubble up as if the modal had never been there, in the other, it should prevent default and return.

The problem is that the modal is non-blocking, so the confirm modal comes up, but the event logic continues and bubbles to the editor's built-in edit event.

How can I capture and pause the current event and only continue it if the I get the desired result out of my Kendo window?

I know I can't and shouldn't make the Kendo window blocking due to JavaScript's single threaded nature, but is there a way to put this event on hold, and only resume it if I say so.

Basically, I want to do something like a `event.Hold()` and if a condition is met, `event.Resume()`, otherwise, do `event.preventDefault()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update**

I tested the code I posted previously and I found that it doesn't work quite right. This is tested and works exactly as you wanted, plus its a drop in solution:

```
var event_store;

function handle_click(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event_store = event;

    //Open the modal here
    //If it's possible, pass the event pointer to the modal's confirm callback
    //instead of using event_store and pass that pointer to fire_event() when
    //it's confirmed
}

function confirm_handle() {
    resume_event("click");
}

function resume_event(type) {
    if (event_store.target.parentNode) {
        var event;

        if (document.createEvent) {
            event = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
            event.initEvent(type, true, true);
        } else {
            event = document.createEventObject();
            event.eventType = type;
        }

        event.eventName = type;

        if (document.createEvent) { //Not IE
            event_store.target.parentNode.dispatchEvent(event);
        } else { //IE
            event_store.target.parentNode.fireEvent("on" + event.eventType, event);
        }
    }
}
```

**Previous**

You could use something like this to "pause" the event bubbling. It cancels the event propagation and shows the modal when the click handler is called and sets the show_modal variable to false. Upon confirming fire_event() is called and it triggers the original event, this time not showing the modal, then resets show_modal back to true. You should also rest show_modal back to true in the event that the user does not confirm the modal.

```
var show_modal = true;
var event_store;

function handle_click(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event_store = event;

    show_modal = !show_modal;
    if (show_modal) {
        //Open the modal here
        //If it's possible, pass the event pointer to the modal's confirm callback
        //instead of using event_store and pass that pointer to fire_event() when
        //it's confirmed
    }
}

function fire_event() {
    if (document.createEvent) { //Not IE
        element.dispatchEvent(event_store);
    } else { //IE
        element.fireEvent("on" + event_store.eventType, event_store);
    }
}
```

Comment: I know its not generally accepted, but it may be possible to extend the native event object to support pausing like this and use event.hold() and event.resume()

Comment: Very nice! JS never ceases to amaze me.

Comment: Sorry, I had overlooked something in the original answer. I made a couple revisions and simplified the implementation. This should work just how you wanted.

Answer (score 2):

What you should actually be doing is

1. call e.preventDefault() in the handler before showing your dialog
2. when your dialog is confirmed (or rejected, I don't know the requirements), use the API method to start editing the scheduler event

This should get you started (will only work for the first edit; you'll want to reset the `_confirmed` condition someplace):

```
edit: function (e) {
    if (!this._confirmed) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // your dialog logic here..
        if (window.confirm("Confirm edit?")) {
            this._confirmed = true;
            // in your code, you probably won't need the setTimeout wrapper
            setTimeout(function () { 
                $("#scheduler").getKendoScheduler().editEvent(e.event);
            }, 5);
            // at some point, you'll probably want to reset this._confirmed
        }
    }
},
```

([see it work](http://trykendoui.telerik.com/@lhoeppner/OzaW/2))

Comment: The events aren't necessarily all Kendo events. The method I posted would allow resuming native javascript events. Also, preventDefault won't stop the event from propagating to parent elements. Also, I can't find any documentation at all for the getKendoScheduler function.

Comment: @aecend Your solution is probably fine for DOM events, and I suppose the question is ambiguous now since it's talking about JS events but also about a Kendo UI widget; 
in the case of a Kendo Scheduler, the event will always be a Kendo event; the preventDefault implementation is also Kendo specific (and in this case, it simply prevents editing the event, there is no bubbling with that widget);
getKendoScheduler is equivalent to .data("kendoScheduler") - I'm not sure if it's documented anywhere