# Are kendo ui events (or events from other frameworks) Javascript events?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, dom-events

Are kendo ui events Javascript events?

Or are they a different type altogether?

The reason I ask, is because I tried to implement the answer from the following Stack Overflow question:

[Javascript: cancel or let an event continue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667274/javascript-cancel-or-let-an-event-continue)

But the functions one would expect on Javascript events are not there.

Comment: Please share your relevant code, and what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kendo UI events aren't DOM events, so the answer you got on your other question probably isn't the way to go. Kendo UI simply stores an array of event handlers in an array (per event name) and then calls them like this:

```
// events is the array of event handlers for a given event, e.g. the "edit" event
// e is whatever the caller passes in to the trigger method,
// "that" is the observable (typically a Kendo UI widget, e.g. your scheduler)
for (idx = 0, length = events.length; idx < length; idx++) {
    events[idx].call(that, e);
}
```

An event is triggered like this:

```
// the first param is the event name, 
// second the event object passed to the handler
// scheduler is an observable, e.g. a Kendo UI Scheduler widget instance
scheduler.trigger("edit", { sender: this });
```

You can take a look at the implementation of events in Kendo UI [here](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-core/blob/master/src/kendo.core.js) (look for the `trigger` method in the `Observable` class).

Answer (score 0):

They are not, but when it makes sense, they often contain the original event. For example the button `click` event has an [`event` property](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/button/events/click) with the DOM click event:

```
<button id="button" type="button">Edit</button> <script>
$("#button").kendoButton({
    click: function(e) {
        alert(e.event.target.tagName);
    }
}); </script>
```