# I Need to fire an event after stopPropagation has been called

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to fire an event after stopPropagation has been called.

I am hiding the div on html click and when someone clicks on the `notif_noti` button I am showing the div which then loads some items with the id `#freq`.

The problem is `#freq` will be inside `#notification_load` which is inside of `#notification_box` and the `stopPropagation` is attached to `#notif_noti` and also `#notification_box` so basically when you click on these two items it will not fire the event I am trying to fire. e.g you can not `.click()` on `#freq` because it will not register because it is inside of `#notification_box`

Hopefully someone can help me as to how to achieve this. If you do not understand I will try to rewrite this for you.

Thanks

```
$("#notif_noti, #notification_box").click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation(); 
});

$("#notif_noti").click(function() {
    $("#notification_box").show();
    $("#notification_load").html('<div style="width:100%; text-align:center;   height: 20px;line-height: 50px;padding-top: 20px;padding-bottom: 20px;color: #999;"><i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin" style="font-size:20px;"></i></div>');
});

$("html").click(function() {
    $("#notification_box").hide();
});
```

```html
<div id='notification_box'>
    <div id='notification_arrow'></div>
    <div id='notification_hd'>
        <span id='notification_header' style='padding-left:05px;'></span>
    </div>
    <div id='notification_load'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where are the `#notif_noti` and `#freq` elements in your HTML?

Comment: This is an x/y problem. You're not doing it right, you shouldn't be stopping the propagation, you should just check if the click originated from within the box or not and act accordingly

Comment: Can you make a fiddle to show your problem in a live example

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403615/use-jquery-to-hide-a-div-when-the-user-clicks-outside-of-it

Comment: could not find `div with id #notif_noti`

Comment: I havent included the notif_noti div because its just a button.

Comment: the #freq div is inside the #notification_load div which is loaded through jquery .load()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provide the full code snippet.  remaining that once call the event.stopPropagation() method. it can not be resumed so you use the below work around:

```
var stop = false;
// do your logic here
if(stop){
    event.stopPropagation();
}
```

Comment: refers this stack over flow link:        http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7811959/how-to-continue-event-propagation-after-cancelling

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e)
{
var container = $("YOUR CONTAINER SELECTOR");

if (!container.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
    && container.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
{
    container.hide();
}
```

});

this works. thanks.